# Type mismatch error in Scala. found : Long, required: String

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I have the following piece of code in Scala.

```scala
    metricReplies.foreach(reply => {
      for ((id, futLoad) <- reply.data) {
        loads(id) = loads.getOrElse(id, 0) + futLoad
      }
    })
```

`metricReplies` is of type Seq[FutureLoadMetrics]. Class `FutureLoadMetrics` has a field `data` which is of type Map[VirtualId, Long]. `loads` is of type `mutable.HashMap[VirtualId, Long]`.

I am getting a compilation error as below at the occurrence of `futLoad` after the `+` sign:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Long
 required: String
        loads(wId) = loads.getOrElse(wId, 0) + futLoad
```

The error goes away if I remove `futLoad` after `+`. I tried searching for the reason and there are a couple of post about `Type mismatch` in scala, but none seemed to match my scenario. I cannot figure out why it requires String?

Comment: Change `0` to `0L`.

Comment: I can't believe how misleading that error message is. Thanks. That worked.

Comment: It's because the `get` part of `getOrElse()` returns a `Long` but if the `Else` part returns an `Int` then the LUB is `AnyVal` and the `+` method on an `AnyVal` expects a `String` argument. Anyway, since this is a simple typo kind of error, you might as well just delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying 0 to 0L should fix the issue.

Generally to debug such issues I just write an instruction like
`a = loads.getOrElse(wId, 0)` and then check the type of a. In the above case, `a` is of type `AnyVal`.

Comment: that's a good point regarding debugging. don't know why your answer is downvoted. Upvoting it now.